# $f + g$ if $f$ is differentiable but $g$ is undifferentiable

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading through Spivak and a remark he makes puzzles me

> If we consider $f(x) = \begin{cases}
> x^3 \sin \dfrac{1}{x}, &x \neq 0\\[5pt]
> 0, & x = 0
> \end{cases}$
>
> Then $f'(x) = \begin{cases}
> 3x^2 \sin \dfrac{1}{x} - x \cos \dfrac{1}{x}, &x \neq 0 \\
> 0, &x = 0
> \end{cases}$
>
> In this case $f'$ is continuous at $0$, but $f''(0)$ does not exist (**because the expression $3x^2 \sin \dfrac{1}{x}$ is differentiable at 0 but the expression $-x \cos \dfrac{1}{x}$ is not)**.

Specifically, the 'because'. Does he mean to say that if $f$ is differentiable but $g$ is undifferentiable, then $f + g$ is likely or certainly to be undifferentiable? Or was he just being a bit careless with his wording, and referring only to this particular example?

Comment: If $f$ and $f+g$ are differentiable at $a$, then $g=(f+g)-f$ is also differentiable at $a$.

Comment: "undifferentiable" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user @Randall already points out, if $f$ and $f+g$ are differentiable at a point $a$, then $g=(f+g)-f$ is also differentiable at $a$. In particular, it's enough that Spivak points out one of the terms is differentiable at $0$ while the other is not; this guarantees the sum of the terms is not differentiable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow the arguement. I'm not supposing $f + g$ is differentiable; I'm just suppose $f$ is and $g$ is not.

Comment: @user_hello1 I see what you mean. The conclusion by Clayton (I think) is that when you know that the result is differentiable at $x_0$, then both $f$ and $g$ are at $x_0$.

Comment: @user_hello1: Correct. Since $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $g$ is not differentiable at $0$, then $f+g$ cannot be differentiable at $0$; if $f+g$ *were* differentiable, then we'd also have $(f+g)-f$ differentiable, which is a contradiction since we know $g$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @user_hello1 hmmm. I don't think so. Consider $f(x)=|x| $ and $g(x)= -|x| $. The function addition $f+g$ gives 0 everywhere (and it is differentiable). However, $f$ and $g$ were not. Thus, the statement '$f+g$ is differentiable if and only if $f$ AND $g$ are differentiable' is not true in general.

Comment: @user_hello1: Not quite, as tempting as it might be to think that; in fact, all we can say is that if $f+g$ is differentiable, then $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable or both nondifferentiable (consider a nondifferentiable function $h$; then $(f+h)-h$ is differentiable, but neither of the individual terms will be differentiable).

Comment: @Clayton So to wrap up. If $f+g$ IS differentiable then it can't be that exactly one of them is non-differentiable, it only means that either both of them are differentiable or both of them are not differentiable. If $f+g$ is NOT differentiable then it can't be that both of them are differentiable, it implies that exactly one of them is non-differentiable or they can be both non-differentiable (we have to be careful with this case as it appears in the scenario where we have $f+g$ is differentiable). Are those assertions correct ?

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis: I'm not entirely sure what you mean for the final part. To phrase it my own way: if $f+g$ is not differentiable, then at least one of $f,g$ is not differentiable. It may be the case that both are not differentiable, so we can only get away with the knowledge of at least one failing to be differentiable.

Comment: @Clayton yeah that is right and more general. I was trying to emphasize on the fact that if $f$ and $g$ are not differentiable then $f+g$ might or might not be differentiable. However, i started from knowing that $f+g$ is not differentiable so there is no need for that distinction. Nevertheless, your statement was logically perfect and general.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Clayton a doubt: your proof by contradiction (the comment upvoted two times) assumes that $(f + g)' = f' + g'$. Yet we cannot say that, if we do not know that  $f'$ and $g'$ both exist. Because the theorem I have learned is that IF $f'$ and $g'$ (exist), then $(f + g)' = f' + g'$. And though we know $(f +g)'$ exists, we cannot state its 'identity' if we do not know that both $f'$ and $g'$ do as well.

Comment: @user: it is enough that one is differentiable; then if $f+g$ is differentiable and $f$ is differentiable, it *must* be the case that $g=(f+g)-f$ is differentiable and $g’=(f+g)’-f’$.

Comment: @Clayton Ah. I got it now.